# How to add or update info to an existing list in python

Tags: python, pandas

All I want to do is to populate a list of unique customers with their corresponding year of birth. Most so to write it back to my df to fill those empty spaces. Both John and Mike's names appear twice on the list. John provided his year of birth the first time he purchased an item but did not do so the second time. Whereas Mike did the opposite of What John did. Below is a sample of my dataframe on customers transactions.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': [2020-06-01, 2020-06-01, 2020-06-01, 2020-06-19, 2020-06-20, 2020-06-22,
                            2020-06-24, 2020-06-25],
                    'cst_names': ['John', 'Mike', 'Ndara', 'John', 'Kasiku', 'Mike', 'Alter', 'Lee'],
                    'birth_year': [1979, '', 1977, '', 1980,  1986, 1986, 2000],
                    'Price': [2000, 300, 375, 800, 3000, 199, 250, 600] })
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
unique_lst = {'John': 1979,  'Mike': 1986, 'Ndara': 1977, 'Kasiku': 1980, 'Alter': 1986, 'Lee':2000 }
```

Once I have this info, I want to write it back to my df and update the missing spaces

I tried using zip and set but I don't seem to get it right.

```
a_dict = dict(zip(df.cst_names, df.birth_year))
```

I tried a for loop and tuple but still i can't figure it out

Comment: `df[df.birth_year != ''].reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to delete empty dates first, then zipped.
I hope it works for you.

```
df_altered = df.drop(df[df['birth_year']==''].index)
a_dict = dict(zip(df_altered.cst_names, df_altered.birth_year))
a_dict
```

Comment: Yes, it works for me. Now I want to use a_dict to assign fill the missing gaps. How can I possible achieve that?

Comment: df.loc[df['birth_year'] == '','birth_year'] = [a_dict[x] for x in df.loc[df['birth_year'] == '','cst_names']]

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it works, but I think it is quite dirty. In the first part I add by default the age "" and then I update it with the age I got. If you only want the non null birth then the other answer you received is good.

```
dict_ = {}
list_names = df.cst_names.unique()
for name in df.cst_names.unique():
    dict_[name]=""
df = df[df["birth_year"]!=""]
for name in df.cst_names.unique():
    dict_[name]= df.loc[df["cst_names"]==name, "birth_year"].values[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

An apply version

```
result_dict=df[df['birth_year']!=''].groupby('cst_names').apply(lambda row: row['birth_year']).reset_index()[['cst_names','birth_year']].set_index('cst_names').T.to_dict('list')
```